# How to print an array in only one line

Tags: c

How can I print an array without changing line? I have this array. I want to print its element in one single line, for example `(a b c d)`.

```
char word[20][20];  
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)  
{   
    puts(word[j]);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`puts` placees a `\n` after writing `char` array to standard output.  Use `printf("%s", word[j])` instead.

Comment: Put a space before the word

Comment: This works indeed.Thank you.I also added this:  
     `printf(" ");`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char word[20][20] = { "a", "b", "c", "d"};
    int j;

    putchar('(');
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        if(j)
            putchar(' ');
        fputs(word[j], stdout);
    }
    puts(")");
    return 0;
}
```